# Avoid Capital Gain Tax Selling Borrowed Tokens

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law, cryptocurrency, loan

I live in UK, but wouldn't mind to get responses related to any jurisdiction.

better explain with an example:

0. I buy 180Tokens at $0.10 price.
1. 1 year later I still have those 180Tokens.
2. I freeze 100Tokens in a blockchain algorithmic and non-custodial liquidity protocol.
3. This will give me 100pTokens that allow me to borrow up to 40Tokens in the Liquidity pool (pair pToken;Token).
4. I borrow 10Tokens at 10% interest (yes silly because I had 180 of them from the start, but wait)..
5. I sell those 10Tokens at $1 price for $10. (no CGT here as I am not selling my own tokens but I am selling a loan and shouldn't be taxed)
6. Now I have to return to the liquidity protocol 11Tokens (by end of this year or 12.1 by end of next year).

- First of all: is there any of the points so far that triggered a taxable event?
- Second: what is the best way for me to return those 11Tokens but avoiding a CGT taxable event?

  - A1. Get liquidated.
  - B1. Burn 11pToken to get ~11Tokens and use those for the repayment.
  - C1. Use 11Tokens from the unused 80Tokens remaining in the personal wallet to repay the 11Tokens

7. At this point here are the possible scenarios:

   - A2. You can burn the 85pTokens remaining after liquidation (11pTokens plus some 4pTokens fees?) and get back 85Tokens. Final Balance: 165Tokens, $10, No Tax?
   - B2. You can burn the 89pTokens remaining and get back 89Tokens. Final Balance: 169Tokens, $10, No Tax?
   - C2. You can burn the 100pTokens remaining and get back 100Tokens. Final Balance: 169Tokens, $10, No Tax?

I would myself rule out the liquidation scenario being tax free as said in [this message](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64713/can-you-avoid-capital-gains-tax-by-taking-out-a-loan-and-not-repaying-debt) I was inspired from.

Comment: Setting aside all the crypto jargon, this looks to me like a short sale: you borrowed an asset and sold it.  Your country's tax law will certainly have rules for how to pay taxes on gains from short sales.

Comment: What country's tax laws do you want to know about?  Please add an appropriate jurisdiction tag.

Comment: Actually, shorting an asset when you already own more of it is usually just treated like an ordinary sale; I believe "constructive sale" is the term in US tax law.

Comment: I live in UK, but wouldn't mind to hear how things change in different jurisdictions.
Anyway when I lend my Tokens for qTokens, is that a taxable event?
https://liqwid-labs.gitbook.io/liqwid-docs/faq